# Why am I getting a error when passing an integer to a decimal in my stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Why am I getting a error when calling my stored procedure?

this fails:

```
exec dbo.foo 100
```

but this works:

```
exec dbo.foo 99
```

definition:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo
(
   @latitude DECIMAL (16,14)
)
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT 'OK'
END
```

error message:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Procedure foo, Line 0
Error converting data type int to decimal.
```

Comment: The 2 EXECs are the same, no?

Comment: you are correct. fixed question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

decimal [(16,14) means "16 digits, 14 after decimal point"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx). This means 2 *before* the decimal point. "100" is out of range because it is 3 numbers...

Quick example

```
DECLARE @fail decimal(16, 14), @pass decimal(17, 14)

BEGIN TRY
    SET @pass = 100
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   PRINT 'Will not see this'
END CATCH

BEGIN TRY
    SET @fail = 100
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   PRINT 'Will see this'
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the difference between the code that works with the one that fails, but both of them should fail. The first parameter on the `DECIMAL` data type is the max number of digits that your number can have; in your case its 16. The second parameter is the number of digits reserved for the numbers at the right of the decimal points. So you can't have 100 as a `DECIMAL(16,14)`, just 99.99999999999999.